# Laurent series of $e^z/(z^3+z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

> Find the first four terms of the Laurent series of $$\frac{e^z}{z^3+z}$$ in the punctured disk $0<|z|<1$.

We can apply the [formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaurentSeries.html) to get $$f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k$$ where $$a_k=\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\dfrac{f(z)}{z^{k+1}}dz$$ But it seems hard to evaluate those values (say, by residue theorem.) How can we proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the function in the form

$$f(z) = \frac1z\cdot e^z \cdot \frac{1}{1+z^2}.$$

Use the Taylor expansions of the last two factors. Multiply until you know the first four terms.

Comment: So it's $\dfrac{1}{z}\left(1+z+\dfrac{z^2}{2}+\dfrac{z^3}{6}+\ldots\right)(1-z^2+z^4-z^6+\ldots)$, and then just multiply out, right?

Comment: Yes, except that you don't need any term of order $z^4$ or higher, so it is even a little simpler (computationally, not conceptually).

Comment: Nice way that avoids integration completely! I didn't know about this before. I suppose it works because of the uniqueness of Laurent series (so whatever series we get that takes the form of Laurent series, we can be sure it's the only one)

Comment: Yes. If a series representation is not unique, things are much more involved.